# preg_match_all item names and descriptions

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a .txt file that contains some data that **CAN** looks like this:

```
item_name_MyItem1=Nice Title
item_desc_MyItem1=A short description
```

**OR**

```
MyItem2_item_name=Nice Title
MyItem2_item_desc=A short description
```

**NOTE: Sometimes there only is a `item_name` but no `item_desc`**

I want to match

- `MyItem1`
- If its a `desc` **or** `name`
- Everything after `=`

So the expected result is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => item_name_MyItem1=Nice Title
            [1] => name
            [2] => MyItem1
            [3] => Nice Title
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => item_desc_MyItem1=A short description
            [1] => desc
            [2] => MyItem1
            [3] => A short description
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => MyItem2_item_name=Nice Title
            [1] => name
            [2] => MyItem2
            [3] => Nice Title
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => MyItem2_item_desc=A short description
            [1] => desc
            [2] => MyItem2
            [3] => A short description
        )

    // For example: MyItem3 only has a item_name

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => item_name_MyItem3=Nice Title
            [1] => name
            [2] => MyItem3
            [3] => Nice Title
        )
)
```

So far i have this regex: `~(?:(.*)_)?item_(name|desc)(?:_(.*))?=(.*)~i'` i use it with `PREG_SET_ORDER`

The problem with this regex is, that it has on every array an empty value, because of the optionals `(?:(.*)_)?` and `(?:_(.*))?`.

Hope that someone can help me fix this regex, so it matches my expected result.

Comment: why not read the file line by line and explode the equal sign, then you can do a stripos() on the left of the equal to see if it's a name or a description?

Comment: I dont know if its faster that way, because its like 25000+ lines, and not all of that are item names and descriptions

Comment: It is faster and more memory efficient.

Comment: What is the problem with those empty values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read file line by line and split it by `=`

```
$handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
$results = [];

if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        list($name, $desc) = explode('=', $line);

        $results[] = [
            $line,
            strpos($name, 'name') !== false ? 'name' : 'desc',
            $name,
            $desc
        ];
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

Comment: You could also make use of generators in this case, returning a huge array that weights several MB's of data kills all the gains we got because reading the file line by line.

Comment: With a bit of editing it works how i expected it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Justinas' answer is confusing to me.  It looks like it shouldn't work, so I'll post something that I think does.

```
$handle=fopen("inputfile.txt","r");
if($handle){
    while(($line=fgets($handle))!==false){
        $dyad=explode("=",$line);  // split in two parts
        $attrs=explode("_",$dyad[0]);  // split the first part into 3 parts
        if(strpos('item',$attrs[0])===0){
            $result[]=[$attrs[2],$attrs[1],$dyad[1]];
        }else{
            $result[]=[$attrs[0],$attrs[2],$dyad[1]];
        }
    }
    var_export($result);
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Here is a [demo link with some test data](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e2f23a214672f13bc0ebac7b67a7b2e30078faaa).

Answer (score -1):

Remove the inner capture group from your *first* optional part:

`(.*)`     =>     `.*`

So you have:

`~(?:.*_)?item_(name|desc)(?:_(.*))?=(.*)~i`

But you can completely remove that prefix, since it is optional anyway, and you have nothing to capture there:

`~item_(name|desc)(?:_(.*))?=(.*)~i`

Comment: Then i dont get the name of the item

Comment: Indeed, you should only do it for the first one. In fact you should not have that inner capture group at all there, not even anything before `item`.